# Recursion and Dynamic component creation in React JS

Tags: reactjs, recursion, switch-statement, formbuilder, react-forms

I am mediocre in React, but I've to build a program of rendering a form using JSON.
JSON is something like this:

```
{ 
    id:"section_id", 
    elemtype:"section", 
    inner_elements:[
            {   id:"row_id", elemtype:"row", 
                inner_elements:[
                    { id:"col1_id", elemtype:"column", inner_elements:[
                        { id:"text4_id", elemtype:"textbox", inner_elements:[], style:{} }
                    ], style:{}, classes:{}, w:0},
                    { id:"col2_id", elemtype:"column", inner_elements:[
                        { id:"text1_id", elemtype:"textbox", inner_elements:[], style:{} }
                    ], w:0, style:{} },
                    { id:"text2_id", elemtype:"textbox", inner_elements:[], style:{} },
                    { id:"text3_id", elemtype:"textbox", inner_elements:[], style:{} }
                ], w:0, style:{} },
            { id:"row2_id", elemtype:"row", inner_elements:[], style:{} },
            { id:"row_3id", elemtype:"row", inner_elements:[], style:{} }
        ] ,
    style:{}
    }
```

Now I want to achieve this using Recursion and switch, rather than using if-else, I want single component  which can inject other components and can render the structure with nested elements(children) using recursion.

Here is my idea, but it's not working ....

```
import React from 'react'
import ROW from '../../components/FormComponents/ROW'
import COLUMN from '../../components/FormComponents/COLUMN'
import Textbox from '../../components/FormComponents/Textbox'
const FormElem =(props)=> {
console.log('props :: '+JSON.stringify(props));

    const elemType = props.elemtype;
    console.log('elemType :: '+elemType);

    const ELEMENT = () => {
        switch(elemType){
            case 'row':
                console.log('setting row element');
                return <ROW id={props.id} />
                break;
    
            case 'column':
                console.log('setting column element');
                return <COLUMN id={props.id} />
                break;
    
            case 'textbox':
                console.log('setting textbox element');
                return <Textbox id={props.id} />
                break;
            default:
                console.log('not matched with any');
                return (
                    <div>
                        NOT FOUND!
                    </div>
                );
                break;
                
        }

    }

    return (
        <ELEMENT>
            {
                props.inner_elements.length>0
                ?
                props.inner_elements.map(
                    (elem, index) => {
                        console.log('elem :: '+JSON.stringify(elem));
                        <ELEMENT  id={props.id} elemtype={props.elemtype} inner_elements={elem}/>
                    }
                )
                :
                <ELEMENT  id={props.id} elemtype={props.elemtype}/>
            }
        </ELEMENT>
    )
}

export default FormElem
```

Comment: It's usually a good idea to state what exactly isn't working.

Comment: JavaScript Object _Notation_ (JSON) is not the same as a JavaScript Object. JSON is _always_ a string. You have an object.

Comment: I don't know if this will be helpful, but you might want to use a Record, which if you don't use Typescript is just a map (or Dictionary if you use C#). Here is a rough example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-4yn2wy?file=src%2FApp.js